# Python, Removing unwanted files.

Tags: python

I have directory with csv files.  I have this code that makes histograms based on these csv files and places them directly in folders based on their name.  However, for some reason I get an extra copy of that image in the directory itself and in the folder that I created.  How can I stop that extra copy from forming in the directory.  Currently, I have the following:

```
(out_file1, ext) = os.path.splitext(full_name) 
out_file1 = out_file1 + "-" + column + '.png'
fig1.savefig(out_file1)
shutil.copy(out_file1,column)
filelist= [f for f in os.listdir(directory) if f.endswith(".png")]
for f in filelist:
    os.remove(f)
```

However, this will not work because I have other png files in that directory that I do not want removed.

Comment: Can you just use `shutil.move(out_file1,column)` instead of copying?  Or just specify the directory path that you want the file in when you first save the figure?  Something like `fig1.savefig(column + os.basename(out_file1))`?

Comment: Why are you doing `shutil.copy(out_file1, column)`? That creates a duplicate image.

Comment: i'm using that to move the files to the folder called column, because they go directly to the directory instead of the folder called column